# How to get rows which have non-null values in all periods but doesn't exists in other document of same company?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database where there are different components with 'Current'/'Historical' period values. These components can belong to different documents of same company. "period" is a boolean column with - 'current' & 'historical'.

My derived table after multiple joins is like this -

```
company_id       document_id       component_id      value      period
1000                   100             1              456      current
1000                   100             1              870      historical
1000                   100             2              67       current 
1000                   100             2              NULL     historical
1000                   200             2              67       historical
```

**I want to get component_id '1' from above : it has non-null values in all periods for document_id '100' but it doesn't exists for document_id '200'. The values of columns "document_id", "company_id" &  "component_id" is not know so can't be used in query.**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want component that have a document that does not have values for all periods.  If so:

```
select distinct component_id
from t
group by component_id, document_id
having count(value) over (filter where period = 'current') = 0 or
       count(value) over (filter where period = 'historical') = 0 ;
```

If this is what you want, then this is one of the few occasions where `select distinct` is can be used with `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want components that, for a given company, belong to only one `document_id` and have no `null` value.

If so, you can aggregate by `component_id` and `company_id`, and implement the filtering logic in the `having` clause:

```
select company_id, component_id
from mytable t
group by company_id, component_id
having 
    bool_and(value is not null)              -- no "value" is "null"
    and min(document_id) = max(document_id)  -- only one distinct "document_id"
```